# Joomla overriding user components in place of custom modules/pages

Tags: templates, redirect, joomla, overriding, components

Can someone please help me with my dilemma, I have tried contacted joomla dev forum and other means of help but havent got anywhere.

I am trying to override the default user components such as login, password reminder and profile etc..

When my user logs in they are asked to change thier password, they are directed to the default joomla remind component. Instead I would like them to be re-directed to my forum, which has a profile and an edit profile info tab.

I would like to override all of the default user componenets and replace them with my own but i do not know how to achieve this.

I have read briefly elsehwere about using hidden menus to change the default pages redirect to a module, but i cant find any more details on this or can I seem to get to work myself.

The joomla documentation and developer discussions are vast and I have been searching for hours for a solution or tutorial. If anyone can point me in the right direction or help it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This could be helpful:

https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_component_mvc_from_the_Joomla!_core

**Summary**

There may be times when you need to override the Joomla! MVC Component to add new functionality or to completely customise the component. The MVC component can be completely overridden by using the same class names that are used in the component. This is achieved by loading a system plugin before the component is dispatched by the application.

You can create your own plugin to do this.

```
class plgSystemComContentOverride extends JPlugin {
  public function __construct(&$subject, $config = array()) {
     parent::__construct($subject, $config);
  }

  public function onAfterRoute() {
     $app = JFactory::getApplication();
     if('com_content' == JRequest::getCMD('option') && !$app->isAdmin()) {
         require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/comcontentoverride/my_content_controller.php');
     }
  } 
}
```